# The update does not return the selected checkbox

Tags: laravel, checkbox, laravel-8, laravel-9

I'm having an error updating the checkbox when I return to the view containing it; in particular it always returns me the first checked checkbox but not the values selected before the update.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
<div class="mb-3">
  <div for="treatment" class="form-label">All treatments</div>
  @foreach ($treatments as $treatment)
      <input type="checkbox" id="{{$treatment->title}}" name="treatments[]" value="{{$treatment->id}}" {{ $treatment->id == 1 ? 'checked' : null }}>
      <label for="{{$treatment->title}}"> {{$treatment->title}}</label><br>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ $treatment->id == 1 ? 'checked' : null }}
```

In this code, you only added 'checked' attribute if the `$treatment->id` is 1, so only the first checkbox will be checked.

```
@foreach ($treatments as $key => $treatment)
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{$treatment->title}}" name="treatments[]" value="{{$treatment->id}}" {{ $treatment->id == $key ? 'checked' : null }}>
    <label for="{{$treatment->title}}"> {{$treatment->title}}</label><br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: so I get the error: `Undefined variable $key`

Comment: which line? in @foreach line?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I have used $key in @foreach loop and in <input> html element.

Comment: yes ok, but $ key is not defined. Anyway I solved. Go see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the following:

```
<div class="mb-3">
  <div for="treatment" class="form-label">All treatments</div>
  @foreach ($treatments as $treatment)
      <input type="checkbox" id="{{$treatment->title}}" name="treatments[]" value="{{$treatment->id}}" @if (count($quote->treatments->where('id', $treatment->id))) checked @endif>
      <label for="{{$treatment->title}}"> {{$treatment->title}}</label><br>
  @endforeach
</div>
```